# Запуск метода из другого класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Как вызвать метод верхнего класса из нижнего?
К примеру внутри главного класса есть класс на основе модального окна. В этом модальном окне я ввожу название создаваемого файла и нажимаю на "OK", файл создаётся и задача в основном классе обновить список файлов(запустить метод обновления основного класса)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<SomeScreen1>:
    Button:
        text:'Please, push me!'
        on_release:root.view()

<Win>:
    auto_dismiss:False
    size_hint:(.8,.8)
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text:'some text'
        Button:
            text:'leave win!'
            on_release:root.leave()
''')


class SomeScreen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.win=Win()

    def view(self):
        self.win.open()

    def print_func1(self):
        print('OK1!')


class Win(ModalView):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def leave(self):
        self.dismiss()
        #Вызвать print_func с этого места
        #Вызвать print_func1 тоже с этого места


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(SomeScreen1(name='screen one'))
        return sm

    def print_func(self):
        print('OK!')


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Покажите код, в котором вы модальный диалог вызываете в главном классе

Comment: Что-то вроде этого. Была попытка сделать в функции leave запись TestApp.print_func(self), но насколько это правильно? Я не знаю.

Comment: Добавьте в конструктор `Win` параметр `some_screen1`, и инициируйте поле: `self.some_screen1 = some_screen1`. В конструкторе `SomeScreen1` изменить строку `self.win=Win()` -> `self.win = Win(self)`. В `leave` используйте ту ссылку на другое окно: `self.some_screen1.print_func1()`

Answer (score 1):

Работает)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<SomeScreen1>:
    Button:
        text:'Please, push me!'
        on_release:root.view()

<Win>:
    auto_dismiss:False
    size_hint:(.8,.8)
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text:'some text'
        Button:
            text:'leave win!'
            on_release:root.leave()
''')


class SomeScreen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self,main_screen,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_screen=main_screen
        #Создаём и передаём и себя и TestApp
        self.win=Win(self,self.main_screen)
        self.my_name='second'

    def view(self):
        self.win.open()

    def print_func1(self):
        print(self.my_name)


class Win(ModalView):
    def __init__(self,some_screen1,main_screen,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_screen=main_screen
        self.some_screen1=some_screen1

    def leave(self):
        self.dismiss()
        #вызываем метод класса SomeScreen1
        self.some_screen1.print_func1()
        #вызывем метод класса TestApp
        self.main_screen.print_func()


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm=ScreenManager()
        #Создаём и передаём себя
        sm.add_widget(SomeScreen1(self,name='screen one'))
        self.my_name='main'
        return sm

    def print_func(self):
        print(self.my_name)


TestApp().run()
```